# How to fix and recover a "corrupt history file" in zsh?

Tags: zsh, file-corruption

After a reboot, I started seeing a message when loading the shell:

```
zsh: corrupt history file /home/myusername/.zsh_history
```

How can I recover from this situation and potentially recover some of the history?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Found a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150816073829/http://marcparadise.com/blog/2013/09/21/how-to-fix-a-corrupt-history-file/) describing a fix that appears to work for me, while restoring my missing history:

```
mv .zsh_history .zsh_history_bad
strings .zsh_history_bad > .zsh_history
```

Afterwards, you may want to instruct zsh to re-read the history form the recovered history file

```
fc -R .zsh_history
```

Comment: May I ask what does the command `fc -R .zsh_history` mean? I've tried `man fc` and it tells me that `No manual entry for fc`, and neither could the `fc -h` tell me more than the usage. Thanks.

Comment: For more details about the fc command, see [here](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/fc1.html) and [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uhistory.htm). The -R option is not present there, but zsh completion lists, among the options, `-R  -- read history from file`

Comment: Anyone knows what this error could have been caused by?

Comment: @hugronaphor In my case it was that I had to do a hard shutdown of my laptop. This caused some issues for me as I did this during a disk write operation and one of the things that got corrupted was my zsh file among other things.

Comment: For the correct `fc` documentation, see `man zshbuiltins`, also available at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html.  As suggested by Jeffrey, "‘fc -R’ reads the history from the given file".

Comment: in my case the file name was `.zhistory` make a note of that before copy-pasting.

Comment: I kind of got curious about what these commands actually do. I've updated the main answer but added more details [here](https://archive.fo/Tuu0w)

Comment: This caused me to lose my entire history :\

Comment: @nlml Just move the `.zsh_history_bad` file back, and maybe edit the file directly to see what's wrong with it, like the answer from @aksh1618 below.

Comment: already +1'd some time ago, but please be careful, this is only working when you're not using the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` option, which writes also timestamps in the history file: `: 1546079587:0;foo bar baz`

Comment: Does someone know why does it happen? I had this issue twice a week.

Comment: `strings` was not available in my Ubuntu distro. I had to install it by running `apt install binutils`. Putting it here in case someone else ran into this same problem.

Comment: isn't it wiser to use `~/.zsh_history` instead of `.zsh_history`?

Answer (score 30):

Simply removing random characters may also work:

- `vim .zsh_history`
- Remove any strange characters, which would most probably be near the end. (In my case I had a string of `@` in the second last line, following a forced shutdown)
- `:x` (save and exit)

Comment: Of course, you can also use any other editor like ` emacs`  or ` nano` … 

Comment: @rugk Over my dead body. /s

Comment: This solved for me! I also had some special characters (converted from windows format to UTF-8) that had gone bad. Erasing them all solved it. Thanks!